# How to define records count to a table that updated only when the table is updated

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, count

1. I want to defint a view (or something else)
   that will save a static variable of the table count.
   I want this variable to be update only when the table is updated,
   this way each time I call the view it will not calculate the count, just return the value.

in the past someone told me that "select count_bit(Id) from table1" will do the job.
is it right?

1. I want to use the variable in mvc site using entity-framework . How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate table to store the count value.

Create insert, update and delete triggers for table1, which calculates the new count and updates the count value.

But do you really need to do this? Are you having performance problems with `select count(*) from table1`? You know, triggers will slow down all update, delete and inserts a bit.

Comment: I use this info in every page in my site, let's say it's count the Customers. I don't want to add triigers to the table1 becuase this slow down the operations. A friend suggest me to try put this info in partial view with [OutputCache (Duration=10)]. and check the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a Select Count to  the  table ,even if you select just a column and count that for your rows or select the the whole table to count the complete table data...put  your count expression after your update is done .